# How to monitor a folder and see if files are being uploaded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems

I am not trying to do a website, I want to have this python script running as a third-party application. I am trying to have the script monitor every file in the whole computer or in a specific folder to see if any file is being uploaded/read. One example would be uploading a file (such as test.txt) onto Google Drive, and I hope that my script could detect that. I don't really need information about the file, just to monitor if any is being uploaded.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What operating system? On Linux you can use [`inotify`](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/)

Comment: See [Watch a Directory for Changes](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html)

Comment: For Google Drive specifically, they have an HTTP REST API with a [watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch) call you could use via Python's `requests` library. Drive also has a [Python client library](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) you could use

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog)

Here is the demo on watchdog readme

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

```
~/playground » python foo.py foo                                                                                                
2020-01-10 11:42:23 - Created file: foo/1
2020-01-10 11:42:23 - Modified directory: foo
2020-01-10 11:42:31 - Deleted file: foo/1
2020-01-10 11:42:31 - Modified directory: foo
```